lvm details of dm-integrity
I've added integrity checksum to my root LVM volume using lvconvert command:
~# lvconvert --raidintegrity y --raidintegritymode bitmap ...

Is there a CLI syntax to get info/details related to dm-integrity?

Depends on what information are you looking for. LVM itself has these integrity-specific fields for the lvs command
    raidintegritymode           - The integrity mode
    raidintegrityblocksize      - The integrity block size
    integritymismatches         - The number of integrity mismatches.

you can see this by using -o+raidintegritymode,raidintegrityblocksize,integritymismatches:
$ sudo lvs -o+raidintegritymode,raidintegrityblocksize,integritymismatches
  LV    VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert IntegMode IntegBlkSize IntegMismatches
  lvol0 test rwi-a-r--- 100,00m                                    100,00           journal            512               0

if you are interested in parameters for the dm-integrity devices created by LVM, you can get those from dmsetup table:
test-lvol0_rimage_0: 0 204800 integrity 253:4 0 4 J 8 meta_device:253:3 recalculate journal_sectors:1584 interleave_sectors:1 buffer_sectors:128 journal_watermark:50 commit_time:10000 internal_hash:crc32c

and even though hidden by LVM, there are still the metadata logical volumes with the integrity format so you can use integritysetup to examine the on-disk metadata:
$ sudo integritysetup dump /dev/mapper/test-lvol0_rimage_0_imeta 
Info for integrity device /dev/mapper/test-lvol0_rimage_0_imeta.
superblock_version 2
log2_interleave_sectors 0
integrity_tag_size 4
journal_sections 9
provided_data_sectors 204800
sector_size 512
recalc_sector 204800
log2_blocks_per_bitmap 15
flags recalculating


I'm using Debian 12 Bookworm, to which documentation did you refer in order to find the "integrity-specific fields for the lvs command"? My searches return nothing:~$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 man -K integritymismatches
No manual entry for integritymismatches
Thank you very much!

lvs -o help shows all available fields for lvs
